# Deploy Twilio to existing Heroku app

Tags: heroku, twilio

I find plenty of information on deploying Twilio to a new Heroku app, thereby creating it. I'm a little stuck on the process of deploying it to an app that I already have. My app has a lot of data in the database there and I don't want to have to recreate it all. Additionally I would like my app to serve PHP pages as well. Do I need 3 Heroku apps now then? Doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You don't need to build a new application to use Twilio on Heroku. If you already have your existing application all you need to do is add the relevant endpoints for [receiving SMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms/hello-monkey) and voice calls from Twilio and deploy to your existing Heroku deployment. It is recommended that you load your Twilio Account SID and Auth Token into the Heroku config so that you can use them there too.

Is there anything specific you need to know about this? What is the application you have already built?

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that.